# Unique filtered index with multiple conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unique-index

Is it possible to create a filtered index in SQL Server with multiple conditions?

Here is what I am trying to do, but gives 'incorrect syntax' error:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TestTable  
ON TestTable(MyIntColumn)  
WHERE MyIntColumn is not null OR MyIntColumn<>0
```

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple conditions -- but `OR` is not allowed, only `AND`. Your condition makes little sense because `MyIntColumn <> 0` *implies* `MyIntColumn IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Also, see the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, this is the answer I was looking for.  I am new to StackOverflow, and it seems that it is not possible to mark your comment as an answer.  What is the correct way to close the topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TestTable  
ON TestTable(MyIntColumn)  
WHERE ISNULL(MyIntColumn,0) <> 0
```